# Accessing the active directory info using iOS app through citrix

Tags: ios, citrix, xenapp

The iOS app which we developed for our organisation is hosted in a citrix environment using XenMobile. The users can download the app to their iPad devices using the citrix receiver.
I want to know if we can access the active directory information (NTId and password of user etc.,) when we launch the iOS application using the citrix environment.

Is there an api in iOS to access the active directory information through citrix ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you'd have to get your users to enter their AD credentials into your iOS app much like you have to do for your email on iOS when you configure an Exchange account.

Comment: Can you point me to a sample code which saves password like we do for the email on iOS ? Also where does the password gets saved if we save this way .will it go to the keychain ?

Comment: I am not an iOS developer so I don't know how to do this.